# Renewing session using Azure AD authentication in ASP.NET MVC project

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, azure-active-directory, openid-connect

I have configured Azure AD authentication in an ASP.NET MVC project using OpenId Connect. The authentication works, but the problem is, that after 60 minutes the session is not valid anymore. In my application, it's common that the user is idle for quite some time, and should be able to continue work without having to relogin. This is how I've setup the authentication in Startup.auth.cs:

```
app.SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);
app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions {
    CookieManager = new SystemWebCookieManager()
});

app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(
    new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
    {
        ClientId = clientId,
        Authority = Authority,
        PostLogoutRedirectUri = postLogoutRedirectUri,

        Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications()
        {
           AuthorizationCodeReceived = (context) => 
           {
               return System.Threading.Tasks.Task.FromResult(0);
           }
        }
    });
```

I have tried to add session refreshing logic as suggested at https://www.cloudidentity.com/blog/2016/07/25/controlling-a-web-apps-session-duration-2/. The problem in that approach is that login window cannot be displayed in a frame.

How can I keep the session valid until user closes browser window? This seems like a common issue that should have some common solution, but I could not find one.

Answer (score 0):

You can add the below highlighted parameter in your code that under ‘new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions’ section before the class: -

```
app.SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType
(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);

app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions {
CookieManager = new SystemWebCookieManager()});

app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(
new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
{
    ClientId = clientId,
    Authority = Authority,
    PostLogoutRedirectUri = postLogoutRedirectUri,

    Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications()
    {
       AuthorizationCodeReceived = (context) => 
       {
           return System.Threading.Tasks.Task.FromResult(0);
       }
    UseTokenLifetime = false
  }
 });'
```

The authentication session lifetime (e.g., cookies) should match that of the authentication token. The problem is that you need to extend token lifetime in AAD which is set to one hour by default.

Also, please find links to below threads for your reference: -

[AzureAD and OpenIdConnect session expiration in ASP.net WebForms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52753194/azuread-and-openidconnect-session-expiration-in-asp-net-webforms)

[Cookie expiry in ASP NET Core Authentication using Azure AD OpenIdConnect and custom middleware](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37533856/cookie-expiry-in-asp-net-core-authentication-using-azure-ad-openidconnect-and-cu)

Thanking you,